# Select Query to generate and exclude some results by joining two tables

Tags: sql, select, oracle10g

I have two tables named, config and config_exceptions. Both has same structure. Columns are home, configName, data, active.

config table has below data

```
0 config1 my_data1 active
0 config1 my_data2 active
0 config1 my_data3 active
0 config2 my_data3 active
2 config1 my_data1 active
2 config2 my_data1 active
```

config_exceptions table has below data

```
10 config1 my_data1 active
```

I need to write a query to exempt config_exceptions data with home 0 alone to give results, like below

```
0 config1 my_data1 active
0 config1 my_data2 active
0 config1 my_data3 active
0 config2 my_data3 active
2 config1 my_data1 active
2 config2 my_data1 active
10 config1 my_data2 active
10 config1 my_data3 active
```

This result is creating a new set of config results for home 10 using home 0 and exclude the config_exceptions table data. **main columns for comparing is home and configName.**

And I can't hard code as 10, they will be more, but 0 can be hard coded as it is used as base.

Please help me to write this query, I don't have idea. Please give me some idea.

Comment: @downvoters care to explain. I don't have idea about this, so I asked it. Is that really wrong?

Comment: Downvoting without an explanation is rude, and I have not downvoted this question.  However, the question is a bit hard to understand.  What is the logic that creates two rows with config 10?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but how are you supposed to get `10 config1 my_data2 active` and `10 config1 my_data3 active` from the data above?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry for not explained it properly. I have updated the questions, can you please check?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Sorry for not explained it properly. I have updated the questions, can you please check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with your sample, this does work.

```
SELECT home, configName, data, active
FROM config

UNION

SELECT ce.home, c.configName, c.data, c.active
FROM config_exceptions ce
INNER JOIN config c ON c.configName = ce.configName
WHERE ce.data <> c.data
AND c.home = 0
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1a3f/5)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help and came to know about SQL Fiddle too, thanks again. am checking this solution.

Comment: But this query should not depend on data column, i.e `ce.data <> c.data` should not be there, but I remove this I cant exclude. How can I resolve this? could you please help?

Comment: I'm able to remove extra rows by adding where clause. Thanks for  your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
select *
from ((select home, configName, data, active
       from config
      ) union all
      (select 10 as home, configName, data, active
       from config c left outer join
            config_exceptions ce
            on c.home = ce.home and
               c.configName= ce.configName and
               c.active = ce.active
       where config = 0 and
             ce.home is null
      )
     )
order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```